# Check in app billing purchase from Java (not android)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I would like to  offer my paid app users an access to website (back end written in Java). I was wondering if there is a way I can check the merchant account/Inapp billing from Java server code to see if the user has purchased the app? Probably by checking his google email?

Let me know what would be the solution to this problem 
Thanks

Comment: Guessing its not possible for security/privacy reasons. Why not send a push request to the users device and check from there?

Comment: Good idea but Because the device might be offline .